# Bit functions in Think Pascal

Tags: bit-manipulation, pascal

I am converting an old program written on Mac Think Pascal to Pascal on Windows. Think Pascal has functions for bit manipulations, such as

```
btst(n, i : longint) : boolean
bitxor(i, j : longint) : longint
bclr(n, i : longint) : longint
bset(n, i : longint) : longint
```

...and others. If you know what these functions do, please help.

I have found some related information, for example ["Porting to GNU Pascal from traditional Macintosh Pascal compilers"](http://www.microbizz.nl/gpc.html). This document has implementations of the bit functions using bitwise operators like `and`, `or`, `shr` and `shl`. However, I am not sure that the description in the document is correct.

I know approximate meaning of the functions:

- `btst(n,i)` is True, if i-th bit of n is 1, and False otherwise
- `bitxor(i,j)` is bitwise 'xor'
- `bclr(n, i)` sets i-th bit of n to 0
- `bset(n, i)` sets i-th bit of n to 1

However, I don't know what is the correct order of variables in the functions (e.g. `btst(n,i)` or `btst(i,n)`). Also, how bits are numbered? From left to right, starting from 0 or 1? Thank you for any help on these four functions.

Comment: FWIW it should be the same as in MPW Pascal, for which there might be more information available online.

Comment: You don't say what compiler you use now? If you use Free Pascal, did you enabled macpas mode?

Comment: @Paul: Thank you for your useful comment. In MPW Pascal documentation, I found, the descriptions of the functions is the same as in my question. Order of variables is e.g. btst(arg, bitNbr). Bits are numbered from right (low-order) to left (high-order). Hopefully, functions in Think Pascal are the same.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I use Dev-Pascal 1.9.2 program. In options of Dev-Pascal, it is written that FreePascal compiler is used. How can I make macpas mode enabled? Can I make this within Dev-Pascal, or should I install FreePascal? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, needed some more room)

The build in Free Pascal of Dev Pascal 1.9.2 is essentially a beta, and very, very old, and lacks such features since it is 2002 era. But dev-pascal can be used with newer FPC's I'm told. Lazarus is pretty close to recompiling the thing itself :_)

Put **{$mode macpas}** after the program and/or "interface" line (in an unit). Commandline is also possible,  **-Mmacpas** (goes for all compiled by that invocation of the compiler unless overruled by $mode in source)

The functions you name are supported in mode MacPasc, but bitxor is called bxor(). Afaik MacPascal mostly models CodeWarrior Pascal, but since that is mostly a superset Think afaik usually works fine. Some Thinkisms were added.

Since macpascal knowledge is fairly rare, you might want to subscribe either to the main fpc list [main fpc list](http://www.freepascal.org/maillist.var) or the [Mac Pascal List](http://lists.sonic.net/mailman/listinfo/mac-pascal).

The [General Lazarus Forum](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=forum) is also abused for FPC purposes, though I expect less people knowledgeable about old Apple dialects there.

Comment: Thank you for information. I tryed to use mode macpascal in FreePascal, as you recommended. It seems to me that the compiler still does not recognize these bit functions. Also, I tryed to change compiler mode, using menu 'Options' -> 'Compiler' etc. Also, no effect. Probably, I should try Lazarus.  Anyway, thank you to all for help.

Comment: Did you use a recent version of Free Pascal, and not the old one that comes with dev pascal 1.9.2 ? See first paragraph of reply.  I'm told that dev-pascal can be upgraded with more recent pascal versions.

Comment: I used FreePascal Ver. 1.0.12 2013/02/12 (Compiler 2.6.2). When I make the compiler mode "Macintosh Pascal dialect",  FreePascal gives  the following "Error: Illegal parameter: -Mmacpascal". Maybe, this mode works only on Macs. BTW, if I switch mode back to "Free Pascal", the compiler gives error  "Unable to open file D:\...\fp.cfg. Probably, this is a bug of FreePascal. Thank you for your help. I think, this thread can be closed.

Comment: Indeed, it is "macpas" not "macpascal", my bad. I corrected tha answer

Comment: I was able to convert the Think Pascal program to Windows Pascal, explicitly defining the bit functions. I thought that my finding could be useful to someone. Namely, as I figured out that in Think Pascal `btst()` and `bitxor()` are functions, while `bclr()` and `bset()` are procedures. I used `bclr(var n: longint; i: longint)`, and similarly for `bset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Bits are numbered from 0 to 7 in a byte or 0 to 15 in a word. Bit 0 is the rightmost bit. So, if Bit 0 is 1 and all other bits are 0, the integer value of the byte or word is 1.