# Pointer to pointer and NewHandle function in (Think) Pascal

Tags: pointers, pascal, handle

What is a purpose in Pascal to declare variable that is pointer to a pointer? I have a code in Mac Think Pascal. Here is some parts from the code that I don't understand:

```
type
   my_array = array[1..100] of integer;   
   my_array_pointer = ^my_array;
   my_array_handle = ^my_array_pointer;
   ...
var 
   xx : my_array_handle; 
   ...
begin
   xx:= my_array_handle(NewHandle( sizeof(my_array)) );
```

As you see, the last line is an assignment of a type `my_array_handle` to variable `xx`. What does it mean? What does NewHandle function do? (This is an internal function of `Think Pascal`). Actually, I need to convert a `Think Pascal` program to `Windows Pascal`. However I cannot find the description of `NewHandle` function, and don't know how to implement this function using the standard (`New()`, `GetMem()` etc) pointer functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic macos feature, not typically something of Pascal.

I don't know exactly, but it had something to do with relocatability of the loaded program in a non PM environment.

Note that the indirect pointer is allocated via an OS function, which probably means that it is allocated in some table that is maintained by the OS. (so that the OS can move/relocate the program?)

In modern Mac (and other) programming this whole principle is alien. Just clean it up.

**(added)**
If you want to keep these redirections, you could try your luck with something like:

```
     function newhandle( nrbytes:integer):ppointer;
     var xx : ppointer;
     begin
        new(xx);
        getmem(xx^,nrbytes);
        newhandle:=xx;
     end;
```

I didn't add this originally, but I recommend you simply **clean up** these anachronistic indirect references and use my_array_pointer based pointers and getmem or new directly.

The meaning of these indirect references has no use on non m68k Classic Mac OS systems, though afaik later PPC versions still somewhat support them. (PPC is always protected mode)

If you really want the gritty details, you probably want to subscribe to the mac-pascal list.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think that the statement with `NewHandle()` function in the code makes some initialization of pointer variable. I cannot just remove it, because there are no other functions (like `New()`) in the code that initialize the pointer. It is known that it is dangerous to use a pointer variable without initialization.

Comment: See notes added to answer, and please better specify the compiler you are using now.

Comment: (Sorry, I cannot upvote your answer, because I don't have enough points). In your function `result` variable is not defined. But as I understood, the line for `xx` should be changed to `New(xx);  GetMem(xx^, sizeof(my_array));`. Please tell me, if this is not correct. I use an old Dev-Pas 1.9.2. As written in a doc-file, it is possible to use newer compiler (FreePascal) within Dev-Pas (you also pointed it out in other thread [Bit functions in Think Pascal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218767/bit-functions-in-think-pascal?rq=1). I will check mac-pascal list. Thanks.

Comment: Result is the delphi identifier for the function result, that works in {$mode delphi and {$mode objfpc} modes. In old modes you need to define a ppointer local variable, and assign that to the functionname to return it at the end.

Comment: So I was wrong about changes of the last line. Now I just leave the line for `xx` "as is", using `NewHandle` function defined in your answer. Thank you very much.